# Wordpress plugin boilerplate table create

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Hi I have a terrible problem.
I generated the code plug on the page: http://wppb.me/

And now, in no way do I add a table to the SQL database installation.
I tried to do it this way:
includes/class-my-activator.php

```
class My_Activator {
    public static function activate() {

        register_activation_hook( __FILE__,'jal_install' );
    }


    function jal_install()
    {

        global $wpdb;
        global $jal_db_version;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'fnotice';
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
                    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    msg varchar(500) NOT NULL,
                    time DATETIME NOT NULL,
                    type varchar(350) NOT NULL,
                    link varchar(350) NOT NULL,
                    status ENUM('0', '1') NOT NULL default '1',
                    PRIMARY KEY (id) )";

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );

        add_option( 'jal_db_version', $jal_db_version );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__,array( 'My_Activator', 'activate' )  );
class My_Activator {
    public static function activate() {
global $wpdb;
        global $jal_db_version;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'fnotice';
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
                    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    msg varchar(500) NOT NULL,
                    time DATETIME NOT NULL,
                    type varchar(350) NOT NULL,
                    link varchar(350) NOT NULL,
                    status ENUM('0', '1') NOT NULL default '1',
                    PRIMARY KEY (id) )";

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );

        add_option( 'jal_db_version', $jal_db_version );

    }

}
```